# jQuery slideToggle Android Lag

Tags: android, jquery, mobile

I am trying to make a slideToggle work properly on the Android devices. I mean... it works fine, but the slideToggle lags or chops. Here is my code and maybe you guys can help me with this.

**EDIT**
I have been using PhoneGap, and done some research. PhoneGap, apparently, doesn't do well with rendering a lot of media. I chopped down half my content, and realized that the effect works perfectly. However; the effect still chops. Is there a way to optimize PhoneGap to properly render media? I have tried CSS3, but the rendering is still horrible. I changed my images format to GIF, and still no luck. What is my alternative, here? If PhoneGap is the issue, then what should I do to create my Web Based apps?

**jQuery**

```
$( ".info" ).click( function(){
$( this ).prev( ".tut-box" ).children( ".info-txt" ).slideToggle( "slow" );

$( this ).toggleClass( "active" );

if ( $( this ).text() == "HIDE INFO" )
   $( this ).text( "SHOW INFO" )
else
   $( this ).text( "HIDE INFO" );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tut-box">
    <img src="blah.jpg" />

    <span class="arrow"></span>

    <div class="info-txt">
        <div class="txt">
            DISPLAY MESSAGE GOES HERE!

            <div class="fade"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="info">SHOW INFO</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by optimizing my script to CSS3 implemented with jQuery 2. So far; no slow animations or slow actions. I also replaced this...

```
$( ".info" ).click( function(){
```

to this...

```
$( ".info" ).on( 'touchstart', function(){
```

It makes tapping actions respond faster. I've discovered this within posts and jQuery Mobile books. Thanks, for the help, Flash Thunder. We tried xD

Answer (score 0):

I had alot of problems with smooth jQuery animations on Android tablets, but I found a solution that worked for me. Try using [this plugin](https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced) - it basically converts every animation it can to transitions.

Comment: I'm trying that out, right now. I've stood up from 6:00AM to 6:44AM (next day) trying to solve this. I'll give updates!

Comment: Sorry, but no dice. This is a strange issue. It seems to do better when the screen is horizontal. It also seems to do most of the lagging when there is more text inside the toggled element.

Comment: maybe try to convert it to animate syntax instead of slidetoggle... should work.

Comment: Same issue, but I did a small test. I removed the jQuery and realized that all the text slows the Android phone. Is there something wrong with all the text and images? Seems like the text is lagging the phone :/

Comment: Android is pain in the axx when it comes to browser. I noticed one more thing. It doesn't like PNG files.